# Why does generating a mini dump inside a UnobservedTaskException raise an AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, exception, task-parallel-library

I have a process that produces mini dumps when unhandled exceptions occur (using both `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` and `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`). The dump works fine from the unhandled exception handler, but produces an `AccessViolationException` when invoked from the unobserved task exception handler (see example code below).

From what I've read on MSDN and StackOverflow, the key difference between the two code paths is that the latter occurs from the finalizer thread and I'm guessing that the thread state or perhaps security is preventing this operation from succeeding.

Does any one have any information or links that explain why the mini dump operation is failing in the unobserved thread exception case? I'm happy to accept that what I'm trying simply isn't possible, but I'd really like to confirm that and know why...

The code below demonstrates my problem by triggering an unhandled exception inside a task and forcing a garbage collection to trigger the unobserved thread exception. The `MiniDumpWriteDump` invocation then generates an `AccessViolationException`.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution;
using System.Runtime.ExceptionServices;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExceptionTest
{
    public class ClassThatThrows
    {
        public void Throw()
        {
            var t = new Task(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Throwing...");
                throw new NullReferenceException();
            });

            t.Start();
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += HandleUnobservedTaskException;

            var test = new ClassThatThrows();
            test.Throw();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        [HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptions]
        [ReliabilityContract(Consistency.MayCorruptInstance, Cer.MayFail)]
        [SecurityCritical]
        private static void HandleUnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            WriteMiniDump();
        }

        private static void WriteMiniDump()
        {
            var miniDumpFilePath = GetMiniDumpFilePath();

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(miniDumpFilePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                MiniDumpExceptionInformation exceptionInfo;
                exceptionInfo.ThreadId = GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();
                exceptionInfo.ClientPointers = false;
                exceptionInfo.ExceptionPointers = Marshal.GetExceptionPointers();

                var currentProcess = GetCurrentProcess();
                var currentProcessId = GetCurrentProcessId();

                var safeFileHandle = fileStream.SafeFileHandle;
                MiniDumpWriteDump(currentProcess, currentProcessId, safeFileHandle.DangerousGetHandle(), 0x00000000, ref exceptionInfo, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
            }
        }

        protected static string GetMiniDumpFilePath()
        {
            var timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmmss");
            var fileName = string.Format("MiniDump.{0}.mdmp", timestamp);
            return Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);
        }

        [DllImport("Kernel32", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentThreadId", ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern uint GetCurrentWin32ThreadId();

        [DllImport("dbghelp.dll", EntryPoint = "MiniDumpWriteDump", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool MiniDumpWriteDump(IntPtr hProcess, uint processId, IntPtr hFile, uint dumpType, ref MiniDumpExceptionInformation expParam, IntPtr userStreamParam, IntPtr callbackParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentProcess", ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern IntPtr GetCurrentProcess();

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetCurrentProcessId", ExactSpelling = true)]
        public static extern uint GetCurrentProcessId();

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
        public struct MiniDumpExceptionInformation
        {
            public uint ThreadId;
            public IntPtr ExceptionPointers;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public bool ClientPointers;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried pinning the `IntPtr` being passed?

Comment: No repro, no obvious mistakes that I see.  The Windows, dbghelp.dll and .NET versions should be documented in the question.  All I can recommend is adding `GC.KeepAlive(e.Exception);` to the event handler, long distance shot however.  Look for environmental problems.  And enable unmanaged debugging, the Microsoft Symbol server and post the stack trace you see when it bombs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried implementing the suggestion from Yuval from my home machine and couldn't reproduce the problem, which immediately made me consider the version of dbghelp.dll on the original machine at work.

After putting dbghelp.dll from the latest Windows 8.1 SDK in my executable folder, the problem went away, so I can point the finger of blame at an out of date dbghelp.dll and not some obscure C# issue with creating mini dumps from the finalizer thread.

For reference, dbghelp.dll 6.1.7601.17514 demonstrates the problem and dbghelp.dll 6.3.9600.17029 is confirmed to resolve the problem. The call stack from the exception (while not revealing much) is shown below:

```
    ntdll.dll!NtWaitForSingleObject()
KernelBase.dll!WaitForSingleObjectEx()
msvcr110_clr0400.dll!__C_specific_handler()
ntdll.dll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException()
ntdll.dll!RtlDispatchException()
ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatch()
dbghelp.dll!MiniDumpWriteDump()
[Managed to Native Transition]  
    ExceptionTest.exe!ExceptionTest.Program.WriteMiniDump() Line 66 C#
ExceptionTest.exe!ExceptionTest.Program.HandleUnobservedTaskException(object sender, System.Threading.Tasks.UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e) Line 48 C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.PublishUnobservedTaskException(object sender, System.Threading.Tasks.UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs ueea)
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExceptionHolder.Finalize()
```